# Page.Client Script process after the button click event

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

Good Day Every one here is my code

```
 if (type.Contains("Loan Date"))
        {
            prenda.LoanMonth = year.ToString() + "/" + month.ToString();
            string a = servs.CheckLM(prenda);
            if (Convert.ToInt32 (a) != 0)
            {

                Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "key", "myFunction();", true);
                //create a popup if yes process if no exit
                //if yes
                prenda.LoanMonth = year.ToString() + "/" + month.ToString();
                servs.DeletePrendaLM(prenda);
                foreach (DataRow row1 in table.Rows)
                {
                    prenda.Bcode = row1["Bcode"].ToString();
                    prenda.Jprincipal = Convert.ToDecimal(row1["JPrincipal"].ToString());
                    prenda.Aprincipal = Convert.ToDecimal(row1["APrincipal"].ToString());
                    prenda.Cprincipal = Convert.ToDecimal(row1["CPrincipal"].ToString());
                    prenda.LoanMonth = year.ToString() + "/" + month.ToString();
                    user.UserID = Session["UserID"].ToString();
                    servs.UploadPrendaLM(prenda, user);
                }

            }
```

the porblem is that the  `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "key", "myFunction();", true);` doesnt execute as soon as the process pass over it, it executes **myFunction()** after finishing the button click proceses, i cant create a if clause below it because it finishes first all of the process before i can use the myFunction() i need that process first before continuing the proceses below **//**

so can you help me find a work around?

Comment: The best option is to go with a dialog and two event handlers.one is for ok and other for cancel.

Comment: @Sasidharan i really do not know how to make those. sorry.

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form... Click create new user in this page,you will know everything.the change what you have to do is create two methods and call them in jquery..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things that might help

The script block added by the RegisterStartupScript method executes when the page finishes loading but before the page's OnLoad event is raised. >> Where are you adding script in the page (Which event?) try it in OnInit or init complete events.

You can check whether script added or not through IsStartupScriptRegistered method (Page.ClientScript namespace)